# Unique filename output from an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

*I have the following code, but now need to have a unique filename (date at the end) on the sales data file*

```
USE [KevinMayhewLive]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[toFileSalesData]    Script Date: 06/19/2017 13:36:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[toFileSalesData]
as

--xp_cmdshell will shell out to the command line to run bcp
--the user account that runs this procedure should have file access to create and write files
--bcp does not append to files, all data will be overwritten each time this procedure runs

EXEC KevinMayhewLive..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM KevinMayhewLive.dbo.KM_CUSTOMER_DATA" queryout \\SERVER3\Docs\Emarsys_Sync\Customer_data\CUSTOMER_DATA.csv -c -t, -T -S'

EXEC KevinMayhewLive..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM KevinMayhewLive.dbo.KM_SALES_DATA" queryout \\SERVER3\Docs\Emarsys_Sync\Sales_Data\sales_items.csv -c -t, -T -S'
```

Comment: What you mean by Unique file name ? your query has two different file name outputs anyway

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not clear what you want from this question. It seems you want to have a unique name for the SalesData file each time this executes? Any thoughts on the structure of this name? And what is the point of that select statement just before the ALTER???

Comment: ah forgot to remove that (some previous bad advice)

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server 2005? I hope you're upgrading to a supported release sometime soon.

Comment: If only it was that easy....

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe what you mean by a "unique" filename, but if you want to include a timestamp in the filename (which would in most cases result in uniqueness), you'll have to dynamically generate a filename. For example:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM KevinMayhewLive.dbo.KM_CUSTOMER_DATA" queryout \\SERVER3\Docs\Emarsys_Sync\Customer_data\CUSTOMER_DATA_'+REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(40), GETDATE(), 120),':','')+'.csv -c -t, -T -S'
```

Comment: needs to have the date at the end, it is run daily so they (our email people) want to have daily file names for the sales data so they do not get confused.

Comment: I recommend you include the time as well so that you can run it multiple times per day (may not be needed *now*, but someday someone will ask for it. Plus, you'll test it multiple times per day). My code includes the time.

Comment: Why user databasename before xp_cmdshell?

Comment: this is very old butchered code, possibly because we have several databases

Comment: @EdwardHeathcote then it's a good time to fix it, since you're already making changes.